# Is the supremum of an ordinal the next ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I apologize for this naive question.

Let $\eta$ be an ordinal. Isn't the supremum of $\eta$ just $\eta+1$? If this is true, the supremum is only necessary if you conisder sets of ordinals.

Answer (score 9):

When you consider $\eta$ a set of ordinals, its supremum is $\eta$ itself if $\eta$ is a limit ordinal, and otherwise it is the *predecessor* of $\eta$.

The supremum of the singleton set $\{\eta\}$ is of course $\eta$ itself.

However, when dealing with sets of ordinals, it is often more useful to consider the least ordinal *strictly* greater than every element of the set. This operation maps every ordinal (considered as a subset of ON) to itself.

Answer (score 4):

There are two notions of supremum in sets ordinals, let $A$ be a set of ordinals:

- $\sup^+(A)=\sup\{\alpha+1\mid\alpha\in A\}$,
- $\sup(A) =\sup\{\alpha\mid\alpha\in A\}$.

Since most of the time we care about supremum below limit ordinals (eg. $A=\omega$) the notions coincide. If $A=\{\alpha\}$ then indeed $\sup(A)=\alpha$ and $\sup^+(A)=\alpha+1$.

The reason there are two notions is that $\sup^+(A)$ is defined as $\min\{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}\mid A\subseteq\alpha\}$ and $\sup(A)=\bigcup A$.

Both of these notions are useful, and it is easy to see that if $A$ has no maximal element then these indeed coincide. However the distinction can be useful in successor ordinals from time to time.