# The supremum of any set of cardinals (considered as a set of ordinals) is again a cardinal.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

An ordinal $\alpha$ is a cardinal iff no $\xi < \alpha$ is equivalent to $\alpha$. Now, let $A$ be any set of cardinals and $\sup(A)=\alpha$, then for $\xi < \alpha$ there is a $\beta \in A$ such that $\xi < \beta$.  As such $|\xi|$ is smaller than that of $\beta$, and thus it is smaller than that of $\alpha$.

Does this sound correct/in the right direction? If so, could someone help better explain the first line?

Comment: That's correct, I think. Not much more I can say about it, really - it's almost exactly what I would have written.

Comment: Note that you didn't handle the case where the supremum is just the maximum. It's the trivial case, but I thought it deserved to be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

**Fact 1**: An ordinal $\alpha$ is a cardinal iff $\forall \xi:\ \xi < \alpha \Rightarrow |\xi|<|\alpha|$.
**Proof:** Easily by Proposition 6.3 of [https://web.archive.org/web/20170329065559/http://euclid.colorado.edu/~monkd/m6730/gradsets06.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329065559/http://euclid.colorado.edu/%7Emonkd/m6730/gradsets06.pdf)

Here $|\xi|$ denotes the cardinality of $\xi$.

**Fact 2**: The supremum of a set of ordinals is a well-defined ordinal, namely $\sup A:=\cup A$. See, e.g., [Is the supremum of an ordinal the next ordinal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109954/is-the-supremum-of-an-ordinal-the-next-ordinal)

**Theorem** The supremum of any set of cardinals is a cardinal.

**Proof:** Let $A$ be any set of cardinals and $\sup(A)=\alpha$. If $\max A$ exists, then $\alpha=\max A\in A$, hence then $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

If $\not\exists\max A$, then for any $\xi < \alpha$ there is a $\beta \in A$ such that $\xi < \beta$. But then $|\xi|<|\beta|\le|\alpha|$, by Fact 1.*
As $\xi<\alpha$ was arbitrary, $\alpha$ is a cardinal, by Fact 1, **QED**.

++) In fact here $|\beta|<|\alpha|$, but we don't need that fact.
(Proof: as otherwise for any $\gamma\in A$ we would have $|\gamma|\le|\alpha|=|\beta|$, hence $\gamma\le\beta$, as both are cardinals,
so $\beta=\max A$, which was ruled out.)

(This is essentially the proof given above by others; I just wanted to make it clearer.)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the fact 1 not only because the link is unavailable but because it seems false: e.g. $\omega+1$ and $\omega_1+1$ are not cardinal but $$|\omega+1|=\omega<\omega_1=|\omega_1+1|$$ So could you add any details, please?

Comment: I now made $\forall \xi$ explicit in case you missed it. I also updated the link. As $\omega_1<\omega_1+1 \not\Rightarrow|\omega_1|<|\omega_1+1|$, $\omega_1+1$ is not a cardinal. Replace each $\omega_1$ by $\omega$ to observe that $\omega$ is not a cardinal.