# Supremum and infimum of the product of two families of cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ and $(b_j)_{j \in J}$ be two families of cardinal numbers. Then,

**(a)** Is it true that $\sup (a_ib_j)_{i \in I,j\in J}=\sup (a_i)_{i \in I}\sup (b_j)_{j\in J}$?

what about the infimum?

**(b)** Also, can we say $\prod_{i \in I} a_i=\sup (a_i)_{i \in I}$ if at least on element of $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ is an infinite cardinal?

**Note.** The supremum of any set of cardinals is again a cardinal (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661333/the-supremum-of-any-set-of-cardinals-considered-as-a-set-of-ordinals-is-again) and [this](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-36219-3)), and we know both (a), (b) are true if $I$ and $J$ are finite sets.

Comment: (a) is yes, (b) is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to show that (a) holds, clearly, $a_ib_j\le (\sup_i a_i)(\sup_j b_j)$, so $\sup(a_ib_j)\le (\sup_i a_i)(\sup_j b_j)$. Similarly, $a_ib_j\le \sup(a_ib_j)$ proves the remaining inequality.

However, (b) is not true: for example, you can see that
$$\prod_{n<\omega} \aleph_n = \aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0},$$
and this is $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ if GCH holds. However, $\sup_n\aleph_n=\aleph_\omega<\aleph_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: -@Haul Jeon. Thanks for your answer. Is (a) also true for an arbitrary family of sets of cardinals (instead of two sets of cardinals $(a_i)_{i \in I}
$ and $(b_j)_{j \in J}$)?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand The answer is no. Let $a_{mn}=\aleph_m$, then $\sup_m(\prod_n a_{mn}) = \sup_m \aleph_n^{\aleph_0}$ and $\prod_n (\sup_m a_{mn}) = \aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}$. Under the GCH, each of them is $\aleph_\omega$ and $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks agin. Also, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514336/infimum-supremum-of-products-of-cardinals