# Infimum-supremum of products of cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\{\mathcal{B}_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of sets whose all elements are also sets.
If $b,\beta$ are two cardinals such that
$$
b\leq \inf\{ \prod_{i \in I} |B_i| : B_i\in \mathcal{B}_i, \mbox{ for all } i\in I\}\leq \sup\{\prod_{i \in I} |B_i| : B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i, \mbox{ for all } i\in I\}\leq \beta.
$$
Then, is it true that
$$
b\leq  \prod_{i \in I}(\inf\{ |B| : B\in \mathcal{B}_i\})\leq \prod_{i \in I}(\sup\{ |B| : B\in \mathcal{B}_i\})\leq \beta ?
$$

What about the case that $\leq$ is replaced by $<$ after $b$ and before $\beta$?

Note. If $I$ is finite, then it is true by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513048/supremum-and-infimum-of-the-product-of-two-families-of-cardinal-numbers).

Comment: The $b\leq$ side is trivial since cardinals are well-ordered so each $\mathcal{B}_i$ has an element of minimal cardinality.

Comment: Isn't the index $i$ a bit overused? $\prod\limits_{i\in I} |B_i|: B_i\in\mathcal{B}_i$ suggests that members of each set $\mathcal{B}_i$ are indexed by $I$ (but why would they be?) and using the same $i$ for both $B_i$ and $\mathcal{B}_i$ looks like... some kind of "diagonalization"? Are we expected to consider each set $\mathcal{B}_i$ separately, compute product of cardinalities of all of its members and finally take infimum over the resulting set of cardinalities?

Comment: -@ Peter Košinár Note that all components of every element of $ \prod_{i \in I}\mathcal{B}_i$ has a cardinal number. Hence we can assign the cardinal number $ \prod_{i \in I}|B|_i$ to each element of it, and then obtain the infimum.